# Creating a Keystore for Android PhoneGap Build

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build, google-console-developer

I am trying to convert my website into an app. 
I used the additional code of

However, I am stuck at the signing APK point.

Stuck on Step 3:   http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap-build/signing/android/#Android%20Signing

Error Message:   C:\Users\User\keytool -genkey -v -keystore [PRIVATE].keystore -alias [PRIVATE] -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
'keytool' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Could anyone give me some advice on how to enter this code correctly so that I can generate the keystore key and file?

Comment: You are having that problem because your computer cannot find the keytool file.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this ::

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore test.keystore -alias test -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

> test is keystore file name. If you want to change you will change it.

I tried this and my test.keystore file generate.

Comment: Thank you Hiten, someone on Facebook actually provided the answer. It was my JAVA_HOME and PATH under Environment Variables. It needed to be C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_121\bin